# ImageList.Images.Add: Store an image or ONLY the Reference?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, resource-leak

I'm wondering what is actually stored in the ImageList collections. Does it make a copy of the image OR it saves a reference to **that** image?

Let's say I have to add an image from file:

```
string imgFile = @"C:\image.jpg";
Image img = Image.FromFile(imgFile);
imgList.Images.Add("1", img);
```

Does the above code saves a copy of the image and is it ok to call `img.Dispose();` on it?

**OR**

Only the reference is saved to the list? If so, how can I dispose each image after I'm done with them?

Comment: [Bitmap CreateBitmap(Original original, out bool ownsBitmap)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ImageList.cs,431) + Read the notes [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ImageList.cs,71) +  [Dispose() override](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ImageList.cs,587).